# Spring boot provided "spring.datasource.password" can change to "spring.ds.pwd" without creating new bean for DataSource

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My team is using latest spring boot for one of the project.

Spring provides database configuration in application.properties file and for password this is the key "spring.datasource.password"

Now, we want to change this to "spring.ds.pwd", but, the change should not required to create new Bean for datasource is it possible?

I followed below link, but, here new beans are creating to handle the session, which should not be expected. Other search information is also similar.
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-jpa-mysql-sample-app-code-example

Comment: any particular reason you are changing the property name from `spring.datasource.password` to `spring.ds.pwd`?

Comment: wanted to change because of corporate security policy and to perform corporate encrypt and decrypt for passwords

Comment: I don't think without creating new bean you can use `spring.ds.pwd`, because `spring.ds.pwd` is defined by you and its not default propery as is `spring.datasource.password` mention in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: And how would changing the property name would help to encrypt the property? Also adding things to the `spring` namespace should be avoided as that is basically for Spring Boot build extensions (not for 3rd party extension). You can define the `spring.ds.pwd` as alias by including `spring.datasource.password=${spring.ds.pwd}` in your `application.properties`. But as stated apart from renaming the property it won't give you anything.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what I want by overriding the DataSourceProperties java class with same package name.